# Bootstrap Menu bar shows up a toggle in Desktop Mode

Tags: menus, twitter-bootstrap

I designed a new theme in WordPress. I used Bootstrap Menu bar for responsive design but shows up a toggle in Desktop Mode.

[image]

```
<div id="nav">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>          
    </div>
    <?php
    wp_nav_menu( array(
            'menu'              => 'top-menu',
            'depth'             => 2,
            'container'         => 'div',
            'container_class'   => 'navbar-collapse collapse',
            'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
            'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
            'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
        );
    ?>
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

```
add_theme_support('menu');
require_once('wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php');
register_nav_menus(
   array(
        'top-menu' => 'Top Menu Location',
         'mobile-menu' => 'Mobile Menu Location',
      ));
```

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want this menu to be displayed on desktop ?

Comment: No, On the Desktop screen, it display in toggle mode. I solved the issue. Because of bootstrap version conflict, it shows that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide elements based on breakpoints ( screen widths ) - you can use the `display` classes of BootStrap 4 - this might be different if you use an older version of BS.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

A simple example of a class name to hide an element on desktop would be:

```
<div class="d-sm-none">HIDDEN ON DESKTOP</div>
```

This is based on the rule:

```
.d-{breakpoint}-{value} for sm, md, lg, and xl.
```

Where value is one of:

- none
- inline
- inline-block
- block
- table
- table-cell
- table-row
- flex
- inline-flex